# ExchangeService throws "Proxy authentication required" error

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I try to get access to my outlook calendar (Win10).

In the method "AutodiscoverUrl" it writes all the logs and the 407-error. How can I get proxy authentication with ordinary proxy settings (or how can I get the ordinary system settings)?

(The internet explorer has a checked "Automatically detect settings" in the local network settings.)

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = CertificateValidationCallBack;
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("abc@def.com", "secret");

service.TraceEnabled = true;
service.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All;
service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
service.WebProxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;


service.AutodiscoverUrl("abc@def.com", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
```

Logs (shortened):

```
Starting SCP lookup for domainName
Searching for SCP entries in LDAP
Scanning for SCP pointers Domain
No SCP pointers found for '
Scanning for SCP urls for the current computer 
Adding (prio 1) ..[some  values here].... to the top of the list (exact match)
Trying to call Autodiscover

AutodiscoverRequestHttpHeaders:
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Accept: text/xml
User-Agent: ExchangeServicesClient/15.00.0913.015

AutodiscoverResponseHttpHeaders:
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Proxy-Connection: close
Connection: close

 failed: WebException (The remoteserver returns an error: (407) 407 Proxy authentication required)
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation here [UseDefaultCredentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservicebase.usedefaultcredentials?view=exchange-ews-api#Microsoft_Exchange_WebServices_Data_ExchangeServiceBase_UseDefaultCredentials)

suggests

> Setting the UseDefaultCredentials property to true automatically sets
>   the Credentials property to a null reference (Nothing in Visual
>   Basic).

Try setting `UseDefaultCredentials` to `false` as you appear to be supplying credentials via

```
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("abc@def.com", "secret");
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do would be to debug the code and set a break point and actually have a look at the values that are being returned for the WebProxy. Eg you maybe getting the ProxyURL being returned but the credentials object of the Proxy is null so it will fail the authentication. So to fix the issue you probably will need to look at using your own implementation of the IProxy interface (which is pretty easy because it only has three properties).